# File upload with jquery form plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

i have a form with input type="file". it submits using ajax (plugin [jquery form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)).
Server returns json response. There are html tags in json data:

```
{"logs":"<span>vfdvf<\/span>","errors":"<span><\/span>"}
```

but when plugin gets this response it transferred in

```
{"logs":"<span>vfdvf&lt;\/span&gt;","errors":"<span>&lt;\/span&gt;"}</span></span>
```

it is not correnct json. How can i fix it? If there is no input type="file" element in form, all works fine.

Here is JS

```
$('#edit_ext_table_form').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(responseText) {
        console.log(responseText);
    },
    error: function(request) {
        var responseText=request.responseText;
        console.log(responseText);
    }
}
```

Here is PHP

```
$a = array(
    'logs' => '<span>vfdvf</span>', 
    'errors' => '<span></span>',
);
exit(json_encode($a));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helps

```
json_encode($a, JSON_HEX_TAG)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot submit a file via ajax, Html 5 has much better file upload capabilities. But in older browsers its not possible. Not sure if thats exactly what is breaking your json, but your end goal is unachievable.

Comment: i was wrong, it is iframe. "ajax form plugin" uploads files using iframe

Comment: yes thats one of the accepted standard hacks for doing an ajax file upload you put the input type = file in an iframe and then when the user clicks upload you use javascript to submit the form in the iframe which is around your file input

Answer (score 1):

maby you can try **json dataType**.

Try

```
$('#edit_ext_table_form').ajaxForm({
dataType: 'json',
success: function(result) {
    console.log(result.logs);
    console.log(result.errors);
},
failure: function(result) {
    console.log(result.logs);
    console.log(result.errors);
}});
```

Comment: there is the same response. if dataType json then calls function failure bacause it is not correct json